# Spring cannot propagate transaction to ForkJoin's RecursiveAction

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, database-management

I am trying to implement a multi-threaded solution so I can parallelize my business logic that includes reading and writing to a database.

Technology stack: Spring 4.0.2, Hibernate 4.3.8

Here is some code to discuss on:

#### Configuration

```
@Configuration
public class PartitionersConfig {

    @Bean
    public ForkJoinPoolFactoryBean forkJoinPoolFactoryBean() {
        final ForkJoinPoolFactoryBean poolFactory = new ForkJoinPoolFactoryBean();
        return poolFactory;
    }
}
```

#### Service

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private OtherService otherService;

    @Autowired
    private ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool;

    @Autowired
    private MyDao myDao;

    public void performPartitionedActionOnIds() {
        final ArrayList<UUID> ids = otherService.getIds();

        MyIdPartitioner task = new MyIdsPartitioner(ids, myDao, 0, ids.size() - 1);
        forkJoinPool.invoke(task);
    }
}
```

#### Repository / DAO

```
@Repository
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public class IdsDao {

    public MyData getData(List<UUID> list) {
        // ... 
    }
}
```

#### RecursiveAction

```
public class MyIdsPartitioner extends RecursiveAction {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final int THRESHOLD = 100;

    private ArrayList<UUID> ids;
    private int fromIndex;
    private int toIndex;

    private MyDao myDao;

    public MyIdsPartitioner(ArrayList<UUID> ids, MyDao myDao, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        this.ids = ids;
        this.fromIndex = fromIndex;
        this.toIndex = toIndex;
        this.myDao = myDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected void compute() {
        if (computationSetIsSamllEnough()) {
            computeDirectly();
        } else {
            int leftToIndex = fromIndex + (toIndex - fromIndex) / 2;
            MyIdsPartitioner leftPartitioner = new MyIdsPartitioner(ids, myDao, fromIndex, leftToIndex);
            MyIdsPartitioner rightPartitioner = new MyIdsPartitioner(ids, myDao, leftToIndex + 1, toIndex);

            invokeAll(leftPartitioner, rightPartitioner);
        }
    }

    private boolean computationSetIsSamllEnough() {
        return (toIndex - fromIndex) < THRESHOLD;
    }

    private void computeDirectly() {
        final List<UUID> subList = ids.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
        final MyData myData = myDao.getData(sublist);
        modifyTheData(myData);
    }

    private void modifyTheData(MyData myData) {
        // ...
        // write to DB
    }
}
```

After executing this I get:

> No existing transaction found for transaction marked with propagation 'mandatory'

I understood that this is perfectly normal since the transaction doesn't propagate through different threads. So one solution is to create a transaction manually in every thread [as proposed in another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232351/how-to-propagate-spring-transaction-to-another-thread#answer-8796932). But this was not satisfying enough for me so I kept searching.

In Spring's forum I found [a discussion on the topic](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/29662-transactions-threads-how-to-pass-transaction-into-a-new-thread). One paragraph I find very interesting:

> *"I can imagine one could manually propagate the transaction context to another thread, but I don't think you should really try it. Transactions are bound to single threads with a reason - the basic underlying resource - jdbc connection - is not threadsafe. Using one single connection in multiple threads would break fundamental jdbc request/response contracts and it would be a small wonder if it would work in more then trivial examples."*

So the first question arise: **Is it worth it to pararellize the reading/writing to the database and can this really hurt the DB consistency?**
If the quote above is not true, which I doubt, **is there a way to achieve the following:**
MyIdPartitioner to be Spring managed - with @Scope("prototype") - and pass the needed arguments for the recursive calls to it and that way leave the transaction management to Spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further readings I managed to solve my problem. Kind of (as I see it now there wasn't a problem at the first place).

Since the reading I do from the DB is in chunks and I am sure that the results won't get edited during that time I can do it outside transaction.

The writing is also safe in my case since all values I write are unique and no constraint violations can occur. So I removed the transaction from there too.

What I mean by saying "I removed the transaction" just override the method's Propagation mode in my DAO like:

```
@Repository
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public class IdsDao {

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
    public MyData getData(List<UUID> list) {
        // ... 
    }
}
```

Or if you decide you need the transaction for some reason then you can still leave the transaction management to Spring by setting the propagation to `REQUIRED`.

So the solution turns out to be much much simpler than I thought.

And to answer my other questions:

> Is it worth it to pararellize the reading/writing to the database and can this really hurt the DB consistency?

Yes, it's worth it. And as long as you have transaction per thread you are cool.

> Is there a way to achieve the following: MyIdPartitioner to be Spring managed - with @Scope("prototype") - and pass the needed arguments for the recursive calls to it and that way leave the transaction management to Spring?

Yes there is a way by [using pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613451/making-spring-beans-behave-like-threadlocal-instances-for-an-executorservice) (another stackoverflow question). Or you can define your bean as `@Scope(value = "prototype", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)` but then it won't work if you need to set parameters to it since every usage of the instance will give you a new instance. Ex.

```
@Autowire
MyIdsPartitioner partitioner;

public void someMethod() {
    ...
    partitioner.setIds(someIds);
    partitioner.setFromIndex(fromIndex);
    partitioner.setToIndex(toIndex);
    ...
}
```

This will create 3 instances and you won't be able to use the object beneficial since the fields won't be set.

So in short - there is a way but I didn't need to go for it at first place.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with atomikos (http://www.atomikos.com) and optionally with nested transactions.

If you do this, then take care to avoid deadlocks if multiple threads of a same root transaction write to the same tables in the database.

Comment: Ok, that seems like something to look at, but I was hoping to keep my technology stack as it is. Also this is not complete answer to both my questions.